# What philosophical works explore the concept of solitude?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, phenomenology

I am currently working on the solitude of old people during the pandemic time. I wonder if there is any philosophical work that explores what solitude is and how it emerges from different perspectives.

Comment: There is an old book [A Philosophy Of Solitude by Powys](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.260410/page/n3/mode/2up), see [Nydahl's insightful review](http://www.powys-lannion.net/Powys/LettrePowysienne/ORPS.pdf). For something more directly tied to the pandemic see [Baloyannis, The philosophy of solitude](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276914644_The_philosophy_of_solitude).

Comment: @Conifold Interesting! Thanks a lot!